# Get Two tables record with match id in single select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables 1. property and the second is images_property. I have store the images of property into the table name images_property. Now I need to match the record property with property_id field in images_property Where image!="" ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 5 How can I do it within single Select Query.

**The table 1. Property**

id,
userid,
property_title,
description,
status

**The table 2. images_property**
id,
property_id,
image,
status

These two tables are because images can be more then 1 or it can be as many as user can upload. So that is why i create two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT images_property.*, property.*  
FROM images_property, property 
WHERE images_property.property_id = property.id AND images_property.image IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY images_property.id DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: how can I use ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 with it. When i put this command it doesn't work but it do.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" ORDER BY images_property.id ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\

Comment: When I type:
while($testing = $checking->fetch_array()){
     echo "<img src='uploads/gallery/'".$testing['image'].">";
     }
It doesn't gives me record even with echo it doesn't show me image but when i type another field it shows me record?

Comment: @HassanAli you are setting image src without quotes

Answer (score 0):

SELECT P.id, P.userid, P.property_title, P.description, PI.image 
FROM Property P, images_property PI 
WHERE P.id=PI.property_id